# Can't delete autopilot profile because it is still active in intune (but its deleted in intune)

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, intune

I am trying to delete all the autopilot profiles of the devices that are deleted in intune. For some devices this gives an error. I tried to remove the autopilot profile manualy in the interface but i get also an error: `deletion failed. Please delete the associated Intune device before deleting this Autopilot device record.`

After some googling i found that their is a work around to delete the devices in the microsoft store for bussiness web interface. This works well (it took some time before the result was visible). I would like to automate this action with powershell. So i went googling for the cmdlets, but i only find [MSStore](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MSStore/) on powershellgallery. But this does not contain a function remove-msstore-device. Does anyone know a cmd-let to achieve this or a different workaround?

The code that i am using to delete autopilot profiles:

```
$admin = Read-host "Please enter your administrator account"
connect-azureAD -Accountid $admin
Connect-MSGraph -AdminConsent

Try {
    $timestamp = Read-Host "Please enter a date in the past (yyyy/MM/dd)" -ErrorAction Stop
    $date_time = [datetime]::ParseExact($timestamp, "yyyy/MM/dd", $null) 
} Catch {
    Write-host "Wrong syntax for the date! Please try again ..." -ForegroundColor Red
}


$AutopilotDevices = Get-AutopilotDevice | select serialNumber,model,deploymentProfileAssignedDateTime,deploymentProfileAssignmentStatus,Id
$ExtraAutoPilotDevicesToDelete = $AutopilotDevices | ? {
    ($_.serialnumber -notin $IntuneDevices.serialNumber) -and`
    ($_.deploymentProfileAssignedDateTime -lt $date_time) -and`
    ($_.deploymentProfileAssignmentStatus -ne "notAssigned")
} | Sort-Object deploymentProfileAssignedDateTime

Write-Host "There are $($AutoPilotDevices.Count) Auto-Pilot devices detected ..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host "There are $($IntuneDevices.count) Intune devices detected ..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host "There is a list of $($ExtraAutoPilotDevicesToDelete.Count) Auto-Pilot devices which can be removed ..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
Read-Host "Hit Enter to see the list of devices ..."

$ExtraAutoPilotDevicesToDelete | ft

Write-Host "Are you sure you want to delete the $($ExtraAutoPilotDevicesToDelete.Count) Auto-Pilot devices listed above?" -ForegroundColor Red
Read-host "Press enter to continue... (CTRL + C to abort)"

$ExtraAutopilotDevicesToDelete | % {
    Write-Host "Deleting device with serial number $($_.serialnumber)..." -ForegroundColor Magenta
    Get-AutopilotDevice -serial $_.serialnumber
    Remove-AutopilotDevice -id $_.id
}
```

Comment: It looks like there is functionality in the beta version of their API to delete autopilot devices. Are you familiar with making API calls via PowerShell and/or using the GraphAPI? 

Here is the link to that specific documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-enrollment-windowsautopilotdeviceidentity?view=graph-rest-beta&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-1.0.